# How do I use existing CSS to style HTML content in textAngular

Tags: css, angularjs

I am using the [textAngular](https://github.com/fraywing/textAngular) editor in AngularJS to allow existing article-style HTML content to be edited. The CSS classes used to style the content already exist and are available.

I can successfully display the HTML content in textAngular. Now I need it to render as it would in production. The HTML already contains the appropriate CSS classes (not style tags).

The question is, how do I get textAngular to render the HTML using my production CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just include your production css into the page. TextAngular is based on the content editable technology, so what you see and edit is actually HTML itself.

If you want to the css to ONLY affect the TextAngular editor then create a copy of your production CSS with just the relevant classes and append `.ta-bind` (the class on the internal most part of textAngular editor) like so:

```
.ta-bind .your-class { ... }
```